# How to compare socket address in C?

Tags: c, sockets

I mean, which fields of `struct sockaddr` should I compare when I check whether two `struct sockaddr`'s have the same ip address and port number? And what about `sockaddr_in`?

Can I just cast `sockaddr_in` to `sockaddr`, and compare it to a real `sockaddr`?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

First you need to check the family (IPv4, IPv6, or other).  Then you can cast each sockaddr to the appropriate "derived" type like sockaddr_in.  See how Apple does it here: http://www.opensource.apple.com/source/postfix/postfix-197/postfix/src/util/sock_addr.c

Comment: Do you know whether `sock_addr.h` is already included on the Mac/iOS?

Comment: @johk95 as you can see in the url, the source code of sock_addr.h and sock_addr.c are actually from postfix project.

Comment: [Yeah, we know how Apple does it.](https://www.imperialviolet.org/2014/02/22/applebug.html) ^^

Comment: Downvoted because this is not actually a correct way of comparing addresses. Particularly, it doesn't handle non-IP addresses, nor does it handle IPv6 mapping.

Comment: This isn't an answer, because the code doesn't give the definition of either `SOCK_ADDR_IN_ADDR` or `SOCK_ADDR_IN6_ADDR`. However, the code probably compares `s_addr` directly for IPv4, and compares the entire structure for equality for IPv6.

Answer (score 1):

First off, when you are dealing with *values*, you need to use `struct sockaddr_storage`, since `struct sockaddr` is only safe for pointers, or you will run into size and alignment problems.

Second, `struct sockaddr` is what passes in C for a "base class". The first member is `sa_family_t sa_family;` (although, since this `struct` predates struct members being in separate namespaces, each "subclass" uses a unique prefix (I have come across at least 40 subclasses)).

Third - while you might think each `struct` definition is reliable, it turns out that the size of the class varies between kernel/library versions. So, you *always* have to pass the `sizeof()` the actual `struct sockaddr_FOO` in order to avoid garbage. For example, old versions of `struct sockaddr_in6` did not have the `sin6_scope_id` member.

You should probably wrap this in a `struct` for sanity (and provide various helper functions):

```
struct SocketAddress
{
    struct sockaddr_storage addr;
    socklen_t addr_len;
};
```

Then, your comparison code would look like:

```
// returns < 0 if (left < right)
// returns > 0 if (left > right)
// returns 0 if (left == right)
// Note that in general, "less" and "greater" are not particularly
// meaningful, but this does provide a strict weak ordering since
// you probably need one.
int socket_cmp(struct SocketAddress *left, struct SocketAddress *right)
{
    socklen_t min_addr_len = left->addr_len < right->addr_len ? left->addr_len : right->addr_len;
    // If head matches, longer is greater.
    int default_rv = right->addr_len - left->addr_len;
    int rv = memcmp(left, right, min_addr_len);
    return rv ? rv : default_rv;
}
```

But wait! While the above code is enough if you're careful, being careful still entails a lot of details. For example:

- Are all socket addresses going to generated within a single run of your program, or will some of them be read from some external medium? For the latter case, you will want to canonicalize cases like the `sin6_scope_id`.
- Do you have to deal with both IPv4 and IPv4-on-IPv6 addresses (mapped like `ffff::1.2.3.4`) in the same program? The easiest way is to deal exclusively with IPv6 in your program, since the relevant functions also accept IPv4 addresses. For best portability, be sure to *disable* (using `setsockopt`) the `IPV6_V6ONLY` flag. Alternatively, you could enable that flag to help ensure that IPv6 addresses never contain an IPv4 address. (Note that the lookup of `localhost` differs - but this is a general problem for *all* domain lookups, which may return more than one result).
- You need to ensure that all struct padding is zeroed.

Comment: This code doesn't work, and I think the explanation is also missing some words...

Comment: @GregKennedy typos should be fixed now. When I wrote this, I had only proved it correct, not tested it.